# Vb.Net Close Winforms Form by its handle

Tags: c#, vb.net

I have such a problem when creating an instance of a form by code.
Here is one simple illustration:

```vb
Dim h As IntPtr

Some Sub...
    Dim f As New frm_myform
    h = f.Handle
    AddHandler f.closed_ok, AddressOf myform_closed_ok
    AddHandler f.closed_cancel, AddressOf myform_closed_cancel
    f.Show() OR f.Show(Me)
End Sub


Private Sub myform_closed_ok()
    'How to close instance of myform from here by using its handle (h)?
End Sub
```

I would like to close a form (specific instance of a form) by using its handle.
Is this possible in .NET and how?

C# code would also be wellcome.

Comment: While you can [get a Form instance from a handle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.fromhandle(v=vs.110).aspx), you most likely [don't need to](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/147640). Please elaborate on the X part.

Comment: you handle the disposing of the created instance in your code after f.Show, change the code to f.ShowModal() then after that line dispose of the created object. on the other form after the button close click, call the `this.Close()` method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the SendMessage Windows API method

```
SendMessage(iHandle, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_CLOSE, 0);
```

Comment: Beat me to it, though this is kinda overkill when he can just use the form object lol.

Comment: Thanks Pranith. I thought since they provide Handle property that here may be some "vb" way of doing this. hoodaticus, since I have few instances of same form it would be need to make some management of object array for closing specific form.

Answer (score 2):

There is a .NET way of doing this as well by using [**`Control.FromHandle()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.fromhandle(v=vs.110).aspx) and then casting that to a form:

```vb
DirectCast(Control.FromHandle(h), Form).Close()
```